# Can I disable ObjectId in my mongodb documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have large amount data records, and each one has unique id in my domain. So can I disable(do not save) the ObjectID in inserted documents in mongodb? It will take a lot of disk space...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `_id` field is mandatory and you need to provide a unique value for each doc, but it doesn't have to be an ObjectID.  You could use an integer value instead to save space, but it's up to you to ensure each doc's value is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can disable auto ObjectId(autoIndexId) in mongodb by 2 way.

1.If you want to disable the automatic generation of _id field, you can explicitly set it to a value of your choice when inserting documents. For example:

```
db.demoCollection.insertOne({ _id: "myCustomID", name: "John Wick", age: 30 });
```

2.Or you can turn it off by defining this in your schema.

```
{ collection: 'youCollection', autoIndexId: false}.
```

[About autoindexid in official doc.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/reference/command/create/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

use unique id from your domain as _id .. if you donot mention _id . Mongo automatically assigns ObjectId. The type of ObjectId is ObjectID.